# PusherException SHA256 appears to be unsupported como resolver?

Tags: laravel-5, websocket

Estou implementando no sistema a tecnologia de websocket, onde utilizamos o [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server) juntamente com o Pusher, o processo para abrir o canal e disparar os eventos está funcionando normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém de tempos em tempos está ocorrendo este problema, onde por algum motivo quando o Pusher vai realizar a verificação de compatibilidade, ocorre o erro dizendo que a versão do PHP não está compatível.

A minha maior dificuldade é entender o motivo de estar ocorrendo esse problema, pois como eu disso ocorre apenas quando temos muitos usuários conectados no Pusher e o erro ocorre apenas depois de alguns F5. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver essa situação?